# XamlParseException on ValidationError when App launching

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, validation

I created a WPF application with some textbox binded.
I use the Validation Error in order to check if values are OK. The validation seek the Database in order to see if the data entered exists.

If i enter a false value, my validation error catch the error whitout problem :)

Nevertheless, if i enter a good value, and if i close my apps, and go on my Database delete the value, when i re-launch my application, the latest data are loaded, and here...i have a nice Crash : " XamlParseException".

This exception is because i delete a value in data, and, when the validation seek my DataBase, the data is not found.

I don't understand why i have a crash at launching, but not after.

**Here is an example of my validation :**

```
    private string m_strCodeIntervenant;
    public string strCodeIntervenant
    {
        get { return m_strCodeIntervenant; }
        set
        {
            m_strCodeIntervenant = value;
            if (m_strCodeIntervenant.Trim() != "")
            {
                if (m_objIntervenant.ReadIntervenantCodebyCode(m_strCodeIntervenant) != 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(m_strCodeIntervenant.Trim() + " don't exist !");
                }
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("strCodeIntervenant");
            }
            else
            {
                m_objIntervenant.strNom = "";
                m_objIntervenant.strIntervenant = "";
            }
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("objIntervenant.strNom");
        }
    }
```

Here is my Validation XAML :

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="TextBox_Intervenant" TabIndex="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="strCodeIntervenant" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>


---------

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Margin="50,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Foreground="Red"
                    FontSize="10pt"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=MyAdorner,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Here is my XAML.cs ( little cleaning for a better view ) :**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private void InitialiserControles()
    {
        TextBox_Description.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBox_EvtNum.Text = string.Empty;
        TimePicker_Heure.Value = null;
        TextBox_Intervenant.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBox_TypeEvenement.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBloc_Note.Text = string.Empty;
        DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
        DateTimePicker_Relance.SelectedDate = null ;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Evenement> Collection_Evenements = new ObservableCollection<Evenement>();
    Evenement myEvenement = new Evenement();

    private void MettreAJourTableauEvenements()
    {
        Collection_Evenements = myEvenement.GetEvenementsForCliCode(App.obj_myClient.m_strCode);
        Collection_Evenements.CollectionChanged += Collection_Evenements_CollectionChanged;
        myDataGridEvenements.ItemsSource = Collection_Evenements;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = App.obj_myEvenement;

            //Load Evenement in DataGrid
            MettreAJourTableauEvenements();

    }


    private void myDataGridEvenements_SelectedCellsChanged_1(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Affiche le code évt sélectionné dans le tableau, dans les champs modifiable ( en haut de l'écran )

        var item = myDataGridEvenements.SelectedItem as Evenement;         
        if ((item != null))
        {
            App.obj_myEvenement.ReadEvenementebyNumero(item.strEvtNumero);
            TextBox_Description.Text = item.strDesignation;
            TextBox_EvtNum.Text = item.strEvtNumeroString;
            TextBox_Intervenant.Text = item.strCodeIntervenant;
            TextBox_TypeEvenement.Text = item.strEvtType;
            TextBloc_Note.Text = item.strNote;
            DateTimePicker_Date.SelectedDate = Evenement.ConvertToDateTimePicker(item.dDate);
            DateTimePicker_Relance.SelectedDate = Evenement.ConvertToDateTimePicker(item.dDateRelance);
            TimePicker_Heure.Value = item.dDate;
        }
    }

    private void Collection_Evenements_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            (e.OldItems[0] as Evenement).SupprimeEvenement();
            InitialiserControles();
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        myDataGridEvenements.Focus();
        myDataGridEvenements.SelectedIndex = 0;
        myDataGridEvenements.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

        Lbl_CliCodeCliDes.Content = App.obj_myClient.m_strCode.Trim() + " - " + App.obj_myClient.m_strNom.Trim();
        Lbl_CliCPostalVille.Content = App.obj_myClient.m_strCodePostal.Trim() + " - " + App.obj_myClient.m_strVille.Trim(); 

        App.obj_Parametres.LoadDataGridParams(myDataGridEvenements);

    }


    private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        // return false;
        // The dependency object is valid if it has no errors, 
        //and all of its children (that are dependency objects) are error-free.
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj)&&
        !LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj)
        .OfType<DependencyObject>()
        .Any(child => !IsValid(child));
    }


}
```

This crash occurr in production "release" or "debug mode".

The exception is an XamlParseException with InnerException = {"TELOU don't exist!"}
Rather than display "TELOU don't exist" next the textbox ( the warning label), the exception is not throwing.

Anyone have some ideas please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: If your application crashes, then you should get an exception. It would be helpful to post it too.

Comment: I edited my  post : The exception is an XamlParseException with InnerException = {"TELOU don't exist!"}
Rather than display "TELOU don't exist" next the textbox ( the warning label), the exception is not throwing.

Comment: Try this : <Binding Path=strCodeIntervenant> (without quotes)

Comment: Cannot compile whitout the quotes ! :(

Comment: Can you also help us with details of your xaml.cs. What code have you written in constructor of xaml where you are getting this crash? Can you try to assign view model after construction of view? (assuming you know MVVM here)

Comment: I edited the post and added the xaml.cs. I don't use MVVM ( never used it ).

Comment: If you want, i created an other question maybe more comprhensible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054507/exceptionvalidationrule-in-two-way-and-xmlparsevalidationexception

Comment: I have news ! The problem appear because of the observableCollection. When the user input data, it input on the TextBox, then the validation can display the warning label near the textBox. But, when i load the data, the data are loaded in an observableCollection, so, i need to find a way in order to don't check the data when the data are setted out from the TextBox. Have you an idea please ? Thanks

Comment: can you post code that loads ObservableCollection from database?

Answer (score 0):

As a first aid, please subscribe to dispatcher unhandle exception (ideally in App.xaml.cs)

Msdn link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx

This will help you log the crash information.

Try this approach for templatising validate enabled Textbox

> ```
>         <Application.Resources>
>   <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxErrorTemplate">
>     <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
>       <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
>         Foreground="Orange" 
>         FontSize="12pt">!!!!</TextBlock>
>       <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
>          <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
>       </Border>
>     </DockPanel>
>   </ControlTemplate>
> </Application.Resources>
> ```

```
<TextBox 
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxErrorTemplate}"> 
[...]
<TextBox>
```

Refer this article for further details ; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation

Comment: Hello, i subscribe to te dispatcher, but why i need to wrote in the "App_DispatcherUnhandledException() " ? I use your Template, without changes. For the codeProjects links, i already read them.

Comment: App.xaml is entry point for WPF applications. So handling dispatcher unhandled exceptions in App.xaml.cs helps you from not repeating it all places. You can do needful logging and decide further proceedings as mentioned in MSDN article. Regarding the crash you face, Dispatcher unhandled code will help you debug in visual studio to see stack trace and get the root cause of your problem. How are you assigning viewmodel to your view? Have you written it inside constructor of xaml?

Comment: I have news ! The problem appear because of the observableCollection. When the user input data, it input on the TextBox, then the validation can display the warning label near the textBox. But, when i load the data, the data are loaded in an observableCollection, so, i need to find a way in order to don't check the data when the data are setted out from the TextBox. Have you an idea please ? Thanks

Comment: Are you loading the observable collection in constructor of view?(directly or indirectly). One of the prime reason for XamlParse exception is exception getting thrown out of constructor of Xaml. Second thing you may try to do is to remove the validation and see if textbox binding works fine. If application works after removal of validation from TextBox, then problem lies in vallidation template style.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably experiencing a crash in the constructor of your class that defines your `m_strCodeIntervenant` field. Maybe something is using the previously cached 'good' value and bypasses the validation by setting the field directly.

Set a breakpoint there and analyze what is happening.

Comment: The error is when i when my DataBase set the m_strCodeIntervenant value.

Comment: You can't be throwing exceptions in the constructor when Xaml uses it. Remember Xaml is just an object serialization language and failure to create the object will lead to the XamlParseException (although it's a bit misleading). Do some error checking if you must set the value in the constructor or preferrably refactor so you arent doing business logic in the constructor. Object creation should be light.

Comment: but why i have this error only at the App launching. If all my data are ok, the program launch whitout problem.I i input a bad data, the validation exception throw whitout problem.

Answer (score 0):

XAML don't displays exceptions, only on output window.

your code is throwing the error but only shows in output window.

When the exception is on the init of the control it cant handle and blows the application.

don't throw exception handle the error yourself.