# ExceptionValidationRule in "two way" and XmlParseValidationException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, data-binding

I have a WPF application with Data in a DataBase.
I can create new Data in my Appli and save to Database, and i can load data form my DataBase.

For example, i created a Person class.

In my WPF application, i can create a Person and ave to DataBase.
When i create a client, some textboxs are valide with ExceptionValidationRule  , and, if the validation is false, it appear a label with the detail error, all is ok :)

**My question is very simple :** At my App Lauching, in my MainWindow(), i get all my Person object in my DataBase an load it in a DataGrid.

When i load the "Person object", the validation is invoked ( because validation process ar ine the set() functions), and , if there is an error, the

```
throw new ApplicationException(....)
```

is not throwing ! I have the Exception Error ( XmlParseValidationException ) message and not the label that say the error.

It's only when, the Data are loaded in the Person Object.

**So, to conclude :**

If i input bad data in the Textbox bound to the Person Object, if the validation is false, all is ok, i see the error label :)

If i load bad data FROM the data base to the Person Object, if the validation is false, the exception message box appear on my Screen !

**Here is my XAML :**

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox_CodePerson" TabIndex="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="strCodePerson" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

---

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock Margin="50,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Foreground="Red"
                    FontSize="10pt"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=MyAdorner,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Here is my Person Class  ( cleaned for a better view ) :**

```
    private string m_strCodePerson;
    public string strCodePerson
    {
        get { return m_strCodePerson; }
        set
        {
            m_strCodePerson = value;
            if (m_strCodePerson.Trim() != "")
            {
                if (m_objIntervenant.ReadIntervenantCodebyCode(m_strCodePerson) != 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException(m_strCodePerson.Trim() + " don't exist !");
                }
                FirePropertyChangedEvent("strCodePerson");
            }
            else
            {
                m_objIntervenant.strNom = "";
                m_objIntervenant.strIntervenant = "";
            }
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("objIntervenant.strNom");
        }
    }
```

Anyone have an idea ? ( I test my code in Debug or Release mode, and i unchecked Unhandlded Exception in the VS 2012 debugger).

**EDIT** : If i load my Data from Database to my Observable collection on the Windows_load event, i have no bugs, but, the exception "stop" the *LoadDataInObservableCollection* function, so the result is an empty datagrid.

**Some détails :**

```
    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //
    //Fenetre_Parametres param = new Fenetre_Parametres();
    //param.ShowDialog();
    //

    LoadDataInObservableCollection();

    myDataGridEvenements.Focus();
    myDataGridEvenements.SelectedIndex = 0;
    myDataGridEvenements.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

    Lbl_CliCodeCliDes.Content = App.obj_myClient.m_strCode.Trim() + " - " + App.obj_myClient.m_strNom.Trim();
    Lbl_CliCPostalVille.Content = App.obj_myClient.m_strCodePostal.Trim() + " - " + App.obj_myClient.m_strVille.Trim(); 


    App.obj_Parametres.LoadDataGridParams(myDataGridEvenements);


}
```

**And here is my LoadDataInObservableCollection Function :**

```
    public ObservableCollection<Evenement> Collection_Evenements = new ObservableCollection<Evenement>();
    Evenement myEvenement = new Evenement();

    private void LoadDataInObservableCollection()
    {
        Collection_Evenements = myEvenement.GetEvenementsForCliCode(App.obj_myClient.m_strCode);
        Collection_Evenements.CollectionChanged += Collection_Evenements_CollectionChanged;
        myDataGridEvenements.ItemsSource = Collection_Evenements;
    }
```

Thanks a lot :)

**EDIT :** If i use a Custom Validator class, it OK !

Just a question, in order to force the validation test, i need to do this, when i select the line in my DataGrid :

```
    private void myDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Affiche le code évt sélectionné dans le tableau, dans les champs modifiable ( en haut de l'écran )

        var item = myDataGrid.SelectedItem as Client;
        if ((item != null))
        {
            TextBox_Code.Text = item.strCode;
            TextBox_Name.Text = item.strName;
        }
    }
```

:

```
TextBox_Code.Text = item.strCode;
TextBox_Name.Text = item.strName;
```

If i remove this two line, the textbox are corectly initialized because of the binding, but the validation process is not invoked. Why ? Is there a way to force the the validation process and use the full binding whitout :

```
TextBox_Code.Text = item.strCode;
TextBox_Name.Text = item.strName;
```

Thanks :)

Nixeus

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your objects in the `Window.Loaded` event and not the constructor. You can't react to exceptions properly when Xaml constructs your object.

Comment: Hello, i edited my post with adding code, nevertheless, if i move my object initializing to Window.loaded, i don't have the exception error messagebox, but the exception exit my LoadDataInObservableCollection Function :(

Comment: I have news ! The problem appear because of the DataGrid. When the user input data, it input on the TextBox, then the validation can display the warning label near the textBox. But, when i load the data, the data are loaded in an observableCollection, so, i need to find a way in order to don't check the data when the data are setted out from the TextBox. Have you an idea please ? Thanks

Comment: As it sounds when a user inputs he code of a person that doesnt exist the exception is thrown and the validation error shows up on the textbox correctly. You should not then set m_strCodePerson = value because it is invalid data. It makes no sense that your backend systems are storing codes of non existant people. I dont know your entire case, but it seems liek you need to move m_strCodePerson = value to the end of the property setter (at least do it in a way that the internal state doesnt get compromised on invalid user input).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It's better ! I edit my post with my code an a little question :) Thanks